# (Jasper reports) - Page break if the contents of the text does not fit on the sheet

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report

I am adding a [link to a report](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B5IUExS3QCR9TFZOczNwRV9rS0U) generated with fictitious information, in case someone wants to look at the presentation.

As can be seen on page 5, three texts are printed, but
the third did not fit completely. The rest of it is presented on page 6. I needed it to be printed in full on page 6 (**note:** The dashes serve to demarcate the end of the field).

Found: `isStretchWithOverflow`, `isPrintWhenDetailOverflows` and, as
`splitType` put the band as `Prevent`. But this did not work as desired.

Any other tips?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem by setting `splitType` as `Prevent`.